# Trying to install matplotlig on windows gives dependency errors

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

On windows 10 I am trying to install matplotlib with the followig command:

```
easy_install freetype
```

However, I then get the following error:

```
* The following required packages can not be built:
* freetype, png
```

How can I fix these errors on windows 10?

Comment: I was going to write an answer suggesting conda, but someone has [already explained it nicely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563902/python-win-10-installing-matplotlib-requires-packages-freetype-and-png?rq=1). It's probably the easiest/most convenient solution for windows users.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I installed anaconda, but the python script in PyCharm (after restarting) still cannot import pylab

Comment: No, its ok, I just needed to click around in the PyCharm setting to use the new installation as the interpreter... Thanks