# How to install freetype and png for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, libpng, freetype

I'm trying to install freetype (and libpng) for using matplotlib.
I download the tar.gz files and decompress them.
But now i don't know what to do... Usually I use "python setup.py install" but there is no setup.py file.

Comment: What are the other files there in the folder ? and what os are you using ?

Comment: am using Windows 7! Sorry 
I forgot to tell ...
there is a file INSTALL (whitout any extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows, this is not a convenient way to install the dependencies. Use a package manager such as Anaconda.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564374/3919475) for reference.